# Pandas DataFrame to_html ou iterar sobre os dados no template?

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-templates

Na verdade eu queria iterar sobre os dados no template?

Mas como eu faço para jogar os dados do meu pivot no contexto e tratá-los no template?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
pv = df.pivot(index='cands', columns='titles', values='grades')
context['quizzes'] = pv.to_html(classes='table', border=0, na_rep = '')
```

No template estou fazendo `{{ quizzes }}`, mas eu queria fazer

```
{% for quiz in quizzes %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ quiz.first_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ quiz.title }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Assim por diante.